# How to deploy WorkerRole project, How to get the exact error during uploading

Tags: deployment, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have to Work with WorkerRole project to deploy some services to perform the data sync with the other databses. i tried to publish but stuck, Internalization, Starting, Preparing, Recovering and finally aborted.

After getting the above stituation i build a simple workerrole project and tried to upload the  result is same.

And i am not able to find out the problem with the same.

Please provide some help.

Comment: Does the worker run locally? If so: Have you checked to make sure your diagnostics connection string isn't pointed to dev storage before publishing?

Comment: I am not able to check it locally, Please suggest how can i check it locally. Actually i tried to run the azure compute elmulator but is starts and automatic shutdown. I don't what is the problem behind this.

Answer (score 0):

A typical problem, when deploying, is having a connection string pointing to the local emulated storage. This is the first thing I'd check if the worker role code runs locally in the emulator but fails when being published to Windows Azure.

Comment: I am not able to check it locally, Please suggest how can i check it locally. Actually i tried to run the azure compute elmulator but is starts and automatic shutdown. I don't what is the problem behind this.